# last ID inserted

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am currently working on an android app which lets you create an appointment for a barbershop.

The appointment information is sent from the app to a MySQL database using passing the URL through StringRequest.

I am stuck on how to a run query where only the appointment created is shown on the app instead of all appointments.

I want to retrieve the data from the server instead of sharedPref because the barber or barbershop can delete/edit appointment through an administration page.

I am currently pulling the $id from a SESSION (add appointment activity) but that does not work as planned.

The SELECT query runs perfectly fine on both app and web if the 'id' in the query is hard coded vs. using a variable.

The list appointment is in another activity by the way.

How can I go about this?

This query only works when adding an appointment through web, not the app:
show.php

```
    <?PHP

    session_start();

    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    include 'wp-config.php';

    global $id;

    showAppts();

    function showAppts() {

        global $wpdb;

        $id = $_SESSION['last_id'];

        $list = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( 
        "
        SELECT *
        FROM wpmq_appts
        WHERE id = $id
        ", $list));

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array("wpmq_appts"=>$list));

    }
?>
```

add.php

```
    <?PHP

    session_start();

    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
        require 'wp-config.php';
        createAppt();

    }

    function createAppt() {

        global $wpdb;
        global $last_id;

        $barberName = $_POST["barberName"];
        $userDate = $_POST["userDate"];
        $userTime = $_POST["userTime"];
        $customerName = $_POST["customerName"];

        $wpdb->insert(wpmq_appts, array(
            'barberName' => $barberName,
            'userDate' => $userDate,
            'userTime' => $userTime,
            'customerName' => $customerName
        ));

        $last_id = $wpdb->insert_id;

    }

    $_SESSION['last_id'] = $last_id;

?>
```

example of system working both on app and web 'show.php':

```
    <?PHP

    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    include 'wp-config.php';

    global $id;

    showAppts();

    function showAppts() {

        global $wpdb;

        $id = 150;

        $list = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( 
        "
        SELECT *
        FROM wpmq_appts
        WHERE id = $id
        ", $list));

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array("wpmq_appts"=>$list));


    }
?>
```

EDIT 1: Added show.php and add.php.

The `$_SESSION['last_id']` only works for web, not the app. I guess it's because I point my browser towards the form I have on a server then I go to the show.php page after I add the appointment. I'm thinking the logic is incorrect but I need some guidance. Anything will be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT 2:
Should I save the 'id' in sharedPred? That way, I can add a hidden text form in show.php passing its value for 'id'. I think this would be the best approach but I only learned programming several months ago.

EDIT 3:
I can also avoid this by adding a login but that would be implemented sometime in the near future after I get the simplest form of the app up and running.

EDIT 4: finally got it work show.php:

```
<?PHP

session_start();
global $customerName;
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="GET") {
    require 'wp-config.php';
    showAppts();
}

function showAppts() {

    global $wpdb;

    $customerName = $_GET['customerName'];

    $query = $wpdb->prepare( " SELECT * FROM wpmq_appts WHERE customerName = %s", $customerName );

    $result = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array("wpmq_appts"=>$result));
}
?>
```

Saved 'customerName' to sharedPref when user creates appointment, then added link show.php?customerName='customerName' to Google Volley

Comment: Show the `variable` vs. `hard coding value` code.

Comment: I'm not at home at the moment so I'll just write pseudo code. SELECT * FROM appts WHERE id = $id . It'll work if I set $id to a hard coded int but if I set $id to $_SESSION['last_id'] , it does not work on app

Comment: Did you start the session?

Comment: Show the working code and the non-working version. Is `$list` in both?

Comment: Added to initial post

Comment: Unrelated: You need to unlearn something you're doing here.  Never, under any circumstances, interpolate variables into a query string. `"WHERE id = $id"` is not safe. Read up on SQL injection and learn how to use prepared statements.  Also, your code needs to assume that malicious users will submit invalid data via `$_POST`, doing nasty things like deleting someone else's appointment instead of their own, etc.

Comment: It is strange to me that `$list` works as a parameter to a function call it is defined in.

Comment: I finally got this to work

Comment: Michael, what do you think about EDIT 4?